# How to put values of a list into a string

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am trying to place several values from a list into a string. The code I have is below:

```
ID = [0, 1, 2]
print 'ID {0}, {1}, and {2}.'.format(ID)
```

or

```
print (r'(ID\s*=\s*)(\S+)').format(ID)
```

This does not work. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong.
The code in the second line prints out the list:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

the first line says:

```
File "tset.py", line 39, in b
    print 'ID {0}, {1}, and {2}.'.format(ID)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thanks

Comment: code doesn't work is not an explanation. do you have any error?

Comment: oh, dear. Look, your second addition has almost no relation to the question originally asked. Please remove it and ask a new question. And you'll need to include proper formatted, full code and not some random pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> 'ID {0}, {1}, and {2}.'.format(*ID)
'ID 0, 1, and 2.'
```

You need to unpack your list.

Your second code doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 9):

You have to unpack the list.

```
ID = [0, 1, 2]
print 'ID {0}, {1}, and {2}.'.format(*ID)
```

See the docs: [Unpacking argument lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).